# Filtering using a list of value in R with lapply() is too slow

Tags: r, optimization, apply, lapply

I have a list of unique stock names (around 12k stocks) with their "previous max income" and a fairly large dataframe. The dataframe has stock names, income, year of that income. For example:

```
AAPL | 2000 | 1,000
AAPL | 2001 | 1,200
AAPL | 2002 | 900
AMZN | 2000 | 300
AMZN | 2001 | 500
MSFT | 2000 | 600
```

I need to check in what year a stock beat its "previous max income" from the large dataframe. Since each company reported income in different years, some have data from 2000-2002, some have more (2000-2005), some have less (2000-2001).

My approach is to filter for the stock name. So, I have to do this for each and every stock. That's why I use lapply() but then it is too slow.

Below is the part I'm talking about.

```
rec_year <- function(sym) {
  recovery_year <- (post_table %>% filter(tic==sym & ni > pre_max_table[pre_max_table$tic==sym]$ni))$fyear[1]
  return(recovery_year - pre_max_table[pre_max_table$tic==sym]$fyear)
}
YearsRecover <- unlist(lapply(tic_list,rec_year))
```

ni: net income
tic: stock name
fyear: fiscal year

The `pre_max_table` contains the list of stocks along with their previous max income. For example:
AAPL | 2001 | 1,200
AMZN | 2002 | 900
MSFT | 2001 | 1000

The `post_table` contains the new data to check against the previous max in `pre_max_table`

The function `rec_year()` first check the previous max net income in the `pre_max_table`. It then check in which year the stock name `sym` beat its previous max. If it found a year, it returns the difference between the year of the previous max income and the year in which `sym` beat its own record.
I then use `lapply()` to apply this `rec_year()` on a list of stocks in `tic_list`

I think the code runs slow because it has to iterate through many tic names (12k). Each time it has to run that `rec_year()` function all over again.

Would appreciate if anyone can suggest a better/faster way to tackle this problem.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to put in words what the code is meant to do?

Comment: Also, what's in `pre_max_table`? Please share a sample. I suspect there's a way to do this faster with a join, but not sure exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Hi, I added the explanation. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Do you already have `pre_max_table` or you calculated it? I guess you can do this without that table. What would be the expected output for the current data shared?

Comment: Oh I already have that pre_max_table. Basically I need to calculate how many years it take for each company to beat its previous max using post_table.

Answer (score 0):

Since `pre_max_table` seems to be a `data.table`, as a first step I'd `setkey(pre_max_table, tic)`, so that

```
  recovery_year <- (post_table %>% filter(tic==sym & ni > pre_max_table[pre_max_table$tic==sym]$ni))$fyear[1]
```

can be revised to

```
  recovery_year <- (post_table %>% filter(tic==sym & ni > pre_max_table[sym]$ni))$fyear[1]
```

Then I observe that using `filter()` *slows down the code*, so I further revise to

```
  recovery_year <- post_table[post_table$tic==sym & post_table$ni > pre_max_table[sym]$ni, "fyear"][1]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But is there a way to do this (finding a certain value for each group) without using lapply() ? I find that calling a function multiple times slows down the code substantially.

Comment: I don't know whether there's a way to do this without calling a function multiple times. As long as no one finds one, all we can do is optimize the function.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to do this (finding a certain value for each group) without using lapply() ?

Here is a way where in contrast to the original approach first all rows with higher income are picked, then from these all but the first for each stock are dropped:

```
# pick all rows from post_table with income higher than that from pre_max_table
ps = subset(post_table, ni > pre_max_table[post_table['tic']]$ni)
# pick only the first row for each stock
pnd = ps[!duplicated(ps$tic), c('tic', 'fyear')]
# compute the "recover" time for each stock (including NAs)
YearsRecover = pnd[levels(pnd$tic), 'fyear'] - pre_max_table$fyear
```